# Make FileChooserDialog allow user to select a folder/directory

Tags: python, gtk

**Can a gtk.FileChooserDialog/gtk.FileChooserButton be set to only allow users to select a folder/directory?**

Maybe I add a directory filter to achieve this? How can I make it so the user can only select a folder?

```
email_dialog    = gtk.FileChooserDialog(title="Select folder",
                                        buttons=(gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL, gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
email_filter = gtk.FileFilter()
email_filter.set_name("Folder")
email_filter.add_pattern("*")  # whats the pattern for a folder
email_dialog.add_filter(email_filter)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170962/enable-gtkfilechooserdialog-to-select-files-or-folders

Comment: @coder, That's not a duplicate; the question you linked is about allowing selection of a file OR a folder, not a folder exclusively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
email_dialog.set_action(gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER)
```

Documentation [here](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkfilechooser.html#method-gtkfilechooser--set-action).